# Router is not reachable from other networks

Tags: networking, router

I set up a DNS server and I want to make it publicly available. My router is not reachable from other networks(request timeout).

The router is a D-link 2560, NAT is on and port 53 is forwarded.

Comment: That’s a different issue altogether. It’s about port fordwarding. Also, you can’t host DNS services properly without a static IP address.

Comment: @DanielB  I can request for a static ip and I've done port forwarding but my host is not discoverable

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the router not being reachable? Can you ping the IP address? If so, can you telnet to the port? Are you sure the DNS server is listening?

Comment: @slhck No I can't ping it, request time out

Comment: Use this site (https://pentest-tools.com/discovery-probing/udp-port-scanner-online-nmap) to port scan port 53 to make sure it's open. Also, you've forwarded port 53 UDP, correct?

Comment: @user54791 It says host is down when I check "Ping host to check if it's alive" box but when I uncheck it, it says host is up and the port is open|filtered

Comment: open|filtered means that it cannot determine whether the port is open or closed because it simply received no response (which should not be happening in your case). It sounds like a port forwarding problem, but it could also be that your ISP blocks incoming port 53.

Comment: @user54791 I used nmap to scan local network using public ip address and It was open, should I call my ISP?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are scanning UDP, correct?

Comment: @user54791 I forwarded both tcp and udp

Comment: In that case I don't think it would be a bad idea to give your ISP a call. You can also try searching Google for which ports your ISP blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Many routers don't allow ICMP request by default on the WAN port for "security through obscurity". Same for telnet. In order to resolve records that are hosted on your DNS you have to inform public DNS what domain you are hosting and where to find it.

For example, if you host mydomain.com there is a server that is responsible for everything that falls under "com" . If the "com"server doesn't know the IP address of the DNS server with a record for "mydomain" (which is different from a record for the application server the user is trying to reach) then the "COM" server won't know how to find your DNS

Also, be sure you read the "How it Works" section on that pentest page. If you run WireShark on your DNS server while the site is testing your IP you will be able to see whether the UDP packets are reaching the intended target